# Does capitalization matter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, capitalization

I can't find a reference about which part of a MySQL query is *case sensitive*.

Is there an overview of where capitalization matters?

Specifically, are any of these *case sensitive*:

- database name
- table name
- column name

Is it tied to the OS? Configurable? Or some other combination of factors?

Comment: What RDBMS you are using is also depends on that. Some of them don't care for case.

Comment: Check out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Comment: @drew010 --> Thank you drew. I was not really knowing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In MySQL, databases correspond to directories within the data directory. Each table within a database corresponds to at least one file within the database directory (and possibly more, depending on the storage engine). Consequently, the case sensitivity of the underlying operating system plays a part in the case sensitivity of database and table names. This means database and table names are not case sensitive in Windows, and case sensitive in most varieties of Unix.

.

> The lower_case_table_names system variable also affects how the server handles identifier case sensitivity

You can read more about the topic [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).

Comment: Which again proves that MySQL sucks. Why would you want to depend on the file system for the case-sensitivity of the table names? +1 for the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the collation. For example if your table has `unicode_general_ci`, it'll support general unicode character recognizing algorithm and it'll be case-**in**sensitive.

Comment: He is asking about case sensitivity of table and column names, not about the case sensitivity of the data in the tables (which indeed depends on collation).